# Can I have function ID for each function being called and communicate with it?

Tags: function, go, pid

I will call a function to build a BOSH connection using `go functionABC()`.

In the function, I will keep the status of the connection by sending ping information. So, there may be a lot of `functionABC()` calls. So now, if I want to get some information from the function, can I have  some way to identify the function by function ID or process ID? Does Go have function ID's or process ID's to identify a function?

If so, how can I communicate with this function? If not, does there exist any alternative way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use a `map` and return a unique id/connection from your function and assign it to the map, something like [this](http://play.golang.org/p/m25-_Ywv3m):

```
var counter uint64

func ReturnStuff() (uint64, net.Conn) {
    return atomic.AddUint64(&counter, 1), nil
}

var m = map[uint64]net.Conn{}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        id, conn := ReturnStuff()
        m[id] = conn
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", m)
}
```

Comment: Thanks OneOfOne. It helps me a lot. The extra question I get is within  the ReturnStuff() function, it will have a loop keep on updating the conn. So how can I get the latest conn when I need it anytime?

Comment: You will need to use a channel, you should do http://tour.golang.org to get familiar with the language.